# Is it possible to connect flows in Twilio Studio?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to link multiple twilio flows together, to make it more manageable and to be able to reuse some specific flow elements just as a payment flow within multiple base flows.

Is it possible to trigger a flow using its webhook url from another flow?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While technically it is possible to link flows together, in practice it is not ideal right now. You can do so by making a call to another Twilio number that is set to respond with your new flow. As you can imagine, this would confuse your logs and is not straightforward to implement, especially if you want to return link back to the original flow later.

For now, the recommended thing to do is to copy the elements to each flow as you need them.

I've registered that I would like to see us implement subflows that you can reuse like this properly, but for now, copying is likely your best method.